# ag-grid theme customization issue and resolve-url-loader failing

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We used ag-grid version 20 in our application and I followed the instructions on how to import the theme and override the scss variables in our React application. Everything went great and worked as expected. We just updated to version 21.0 so we can use the dndSource feature, but our code won't compile anymore. The error we get is
"Module build failed: Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration"

I looked around and this is what libsass library listed:

**Windows line breaks**

Normal windows linebreaks are CRLF. But sometimes libsass will output single CR characters.

This problem is specific to multiline declarations. Refer to the libsass bug #2693.

If you have any such multiline declarations preceding url() statements it will fail your build.

Libsass doesn't consider these orphan CR to be newlines but postcss engine does. The result being an offset in source-map line-numbers which crashes resolve-url-loader.

Module build failed: Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  source-map information is not available at url() declaration
Some users find the node-sass linefeed option solves the problem.

Solutions

Try the node-sass linefeed option by way of sass-loader.

Not sure how to get around this? We use create-react-app and I dont think the team likes the idea of ejecting and then taking over the webpack config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - configure your editor to save files with Linux line endings. Stop putting Windows line endings in your source files, and you won't have that problem.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to post 2 days ago. It turned out someone added scss files on our side with CLRFs, however we did not see this until ag grid was updated (not sure why that mattered). I fixed it by adding .gitattributes and setting *.css text eol=lf. This forces all of our scss files to be in lf at checkout. Until libsass 3.6 comes out this is the workaround